# Can't center a div

Tags: css, html-lists, center

I can't center this div for the life of me. I'm going a bit crazy here. I've tried auto margin, text-align center. I've got it in an unordered list.

js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8V3Tr/

```
#logoWrap {
    background:#F0F0F0;
    text-align:center;
}
#logowrapInner {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}
ul#corpLogos {
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
    padding:15px;
}

ul#corpLogos li a {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

ul#corpLogos li a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
        filter: url(#drop-shadow);
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
        filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
}

#corpLogos img { border : 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto\9; /* ie8 */ }

<div id="logoWrap">
<div id="logowrapInner">
<ul id="corpLogos">

<li><a href="http://www.bellator.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://s513195336.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/bellator.png"/></li>  


<li><a href="http://www.ncaa.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://s513195336.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ncaa.png" /></li>


<li><a href="http://http://www.ufc.ca/" target="_blank"><img src="http://s513195336.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ufc.png" /></li>


<li><a href="http://www.nhl.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://s513195336.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/nhl.png" /></li> 


</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what div you want to center?

Comment: How is `-webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;`—or the majority of that CSS—relevant to your problem?

Comment: Use Firebug, etc. to show you that the UL has quite a bit of space on its right side (logos not centered within it). The divs themselves seem to be centered.

Comment: you seem to be missing closing `a` tags. Also, your inner div is centered within the outer div, but since you have the logos with `float:left` they are on the left side of the div. Try giving the inner div a background color to see what I mean.

Comment: good call on the <a> tags...but not problem. How do I get those floated divs centered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved : http://jsfiddle.net/8V3Tr/7/

Add width to the UL and use margin: auto 0

Only changes here:

```
#logowrapInner {
   width:100%;
}
ul#corpLogos {
    width:60%;
    overflow:hidden; 
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`margin: auto;` isn't working for you because you need to specify a width for the parent container.

Change this:

```
#logoWrap {
  background:#F0F0F0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

To something like this:

```
#logoWrap {
  background:#F0F0F0;
  text-align:center;
  width: 800px;
}
```

See here for a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mp5Vn/